# Spooling count of data with a condition in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Kindly note that I have the below table, I am trying to spool the count of the sum of the **amtpd** by grouping the **duedt** where it is less than or equal to **31-dec-2013**, but the **amtpd** that has the **duedt** of 31-dec-2013 and that has **trndt** between **01-dec-2013 and 31-dec-2013**, should be less that 10000, in this case the count should be 3.

```
   |duedt|         |amtp|       |trndt|
   |10/31/2013|    |2007.1|     |10/27/2013| 
   |10/31/2013|    |8442.9|     |12/16/2013| 
   |11/30/2013|    |10450|      |12/16/2013|
   |12/31/2013|    |2107.1|     |12/16/2013|
   |12/31/2013|    |8342.9|     |3/23/2014|
   |12/31/2013|    |0|          |5/5/2014|
```

I am using the below query but it is giving me zero count

```
   SELECT COUNT (SUM (amtpd))
     FROM ln02rep2
    WHERE trndt <= '31-dec-2013'
    AND (
          (SELECT SUM (amtpd)
                FROM ln02rep2
               WHERE trndt BETWEEN '01-dec-2013' AND '31-dec-2013'
                AND duedt = '31-dec-2013'
              )>='10450.00')
   GROUP BY by duedt;
```

Comment: Does wrapping a TO_DATE around the date literals make a difference?

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't be querying positive contiguous-range types (like dates/times/timestamps) [with an inclusive upper bound, like in `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: If I should not use between then what will I use?

Comment: I tried the solution you gave me but still it is not working